# Anaconda get stuck either at solving environment or executing

Tags: macos, anaconda

I am facing a problem with anaconda. I am currently running on macOS Catalina (moving to BigSur soon).
The problem both when running conda commands or anaconda navigator, lies on the fact that each command using `conda` keyword get stuck at Solving Environment. Now, I have anaconda3 folder in $HOME as usual. I created a folder in Desktop and would like to create a conda virtual env there. I thought at first that I had to reset the path but figured out that also when operating in $HOME conda does not work.
For instance, if I try to simply `conda installing` a package (the same happens when creating a virtual env) I end up with:

```
conda install anaconda-clean
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: /
```

running forever. Some commands however seem to work (e.g. `conda search`)
Any clue about it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: are you behind a corporate proxy?

Comment: @Paul actually I am not. I am a private user...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solving environment getting hung is a common problem and hard to resolve. Usually if you used both conda and pip to install packages then the conda environment may become unstable. Perhaps you may need to completely remove anaconda and reinstall again from scratch to get a fresh anaconda install and create a new virtual environment there and use only conda to install new packages.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I tried to `conda update --all`. It first installed some packages. But then tons of warnings emerged of the type: ```WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(140): Could not remove or rename /Users/federiconutarelli/anaconda3/pkgs/beautifulsoup4-4.9.3-pyhb0f4dca_0/site-packages/bs4/tests/test_tree.py.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)``` When I then tried conda commands back they failed ass before.

Comment: Looks like conda environment is messed up. You can try to list your revisions and revert to an earlier revision which is more stable. See this blog: [link] (https://www.shriramjaju.page/2018-05-30-2-minute-recipe-how-to-rollback-your-conda-environment/)    `List the history of each change to the current environment     conda list --revisions
Restore environment to a previous revision                     conda install --revision 2 `

Answer (score 1):

Hi guys and thank you all for the answers. I ended up by reinstalling conda from scratch after having properly uninstalled it (which is not an easy task and I suggest you to do with dedicated softwares such as CleanMyMac X if you run on Mac and don't want to do it via terminal by removing the anaconda3 folder, which is, by the way, not sufficient).
Looks that anaconda messed up with pip latest release permissions for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but when I tried:

```
conda env update -n tf2 -f environment.yml --prune
```

It worked. In this the -n is the name of the environment.